# and inequality regarding the binomial distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is r.v. with binomial distribution $B(n,p)$. Let $\lambda >0 $ and $\epsilon > 0$. How can I show that

$$ P( X -np > n \epsilon ) \leq \mathbb{E}( \exp[ \lambda(X-np-n\epsilon)] ) $$

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Markov inequality, for a non negative random variable whose expectation exists, like in the case of our $X$, and for a positive constant $\alpha$ we have $$P(X>\alpha)\le \frac{\mathbb E[X]}{\alpha}.$$
Note that in our case $\mathbb E[X]=np$. However, in what follows, this is not going to be used. The argumentation below is independent from the distribution of $X.$ (Except that the expectation has to exist.)

Let $\alpha=e^{\lambda (n\epsilon+np)} $ where $\lambda$ is a positive constant.

With all this,
 $$P(X-np>n\epsilon)=P(X>np+n\epsilon)=P\left(e^{\lambda X}>e^{\lambda (np+n\epsilon)}\right)\le \frac{\mathbb E\left [e^{\lambda X}\right]}{e^{\lambda (np+n\epsilon)}}=\mathbb E\left[e^{\lambda(X-np-n\epsilon )}\right].$$